# Here is the report and login or Here are the report and login or Here is the report and the login?

Tags: grammar

> Here is the report and login

or

> Here are the report and login

or

> Here is the report and the login?

Which one is correct and sounds better?

Comment: Looks like proofreading to me. What's a "login" in this context anyway, if it's not a written record (report) of some earlier act of logging in? @peipel - probably *"Here are the report and login details"* is best, but it's just stylistic choice (avoid singular *here **is*** though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correctness and sounding better aren't necessarily the same thing.

Technically when you are referring to more than one thing, you should use the plural:

> Here are the things you wanted [i.e. the report and the login]

But there are a couple of common exceptions:

1. When things are closely related, they are often treated as a single object

   > Here is your fish and chips.

   How distant that relationship has to be before 'are' is mandated is a matter of taste I think.
2. There's a strong tendency to use the singular form when the first object in a list begins with a vowel, even though it might be grammatically incorrect.

   > Where's Amy and Rory?

   In this case correct grammar is being trumped by smoothness of speech. I cannot say 'Where are Amy and Rory?' quickly. It sounds ugly and lumpy, in fact it makes a pretty good tongue-twister.